# iPhone Dev: Process each frame of a live recording movie for AR app?

Tags: iphone

I'm doing research into AR on the iPhone and am trying to figure out how people are getting each frame of video? I'm wanting to figure out AR using computer vision( OpenCV ). So basically I will have a pattern on a piece of paper that I will find using OpenCV and place a graphic on top of the pattern.

I know about the movie class UIImagePickerController, but am unsure how you would go about getting to each frame.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController` is the means for displaying a camera view and taking single pictures with a camera-like front end. It's not what you're looking for.

Instead you need to look into AVFoundation, particularly the classes surrounding `AVCaptureSession`. You'll want to acquire a meaningful `AVCaptureDevice` (which can be the front or back camera on the iPhone 4 and current iPod Touch), create an `AVCaptureDeviceInput` that references it and add that as an input to an AVCaptureSession. Then just create an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and set it up with a meaningful delegate and a Grand Central Dispatch dispatch queue.

When you start the session going, you'll receive delegate callbacks on the queue you created providing `CMSampleBufferRef`s, from which you can pull a `CVImageBufferRef` and hence the pixel data.

Comment: All I've done is get the image data and play about with it — I've made no attempt at interfacing to OpenCV or any other computer vision or augmented reality code. The whole stuff I've described is less than 150 lines, commented — it's really simple.